# Kernel Density Estimation intuition

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

I just read [this](https://mglerner.github.io/posts/histograms-and-kernel-density-estimation-kde-2.html) article about the motivation for KDE. From what I understand, you are using Gaussian probability density distributions for each datapoint and then, depending on the selected kernel width, you get a KDE curve. I had a few questions:

1. What is the kernel width defined as, for these Gaussian distributions? Is it just the variance?
2. From what I understand, you add the probability densities corresponding to each point to get the full KDE. What does the resulting value curve physically mean? Is it some sort of cumulative probability density?